# Unpickling data from Python 2 with unicode strings in Python 3

Tags: python-2.7, python-unicode, python-3.4

I have pickled data from 2.7 that I pickled like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# coding=utf-8 

import pickle

data = {1: datetime.date(2014, 3, 18), 
       'string-key': u'ünicode-string'}

pickle.dump(data, open('file.pickle', 'wb'))
```

The only way I found to load this in Python 3.4 is:

```
data = pickle.load(open('file.pickle', "rb"), encoding='bytes')
```

Now my unicode string are fine but the dict keys are `bytes`. `print(repr(data))` gives:

```
{1: datetime.date(2014, 3, 18), b'string-key': 'ünicode-string'}
```

Does anybody have an idea to get around rewriting my code like `data[b'string-key']` resp. converting all existing files?

Comment: Pickled data isn't expected to work across versions and implementations, and is a fairly bad serialization method to use even when it works at all because it executes arbitrary code. Have you considered using JSON instead?

Comment: I have a more complex structure that contains dicts, tuples, and tuples of tuples as values and I need to compare versions of the saved data and for this purpose tuples are much more convient than lists. But there are no tuples in JSON (and think also no dates?).

Comment: @Wooble: [but in general pickle should always be the preferred way to serialize Python objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-marshal)

Comment: Preferred over `marshal`, sure. In general it's better to avoid having to serialize objects at all and to just store the actual data.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a real answer but only a workaround. This converts pickled data to version 3 in Python 3.4 (doesn't work in 3.3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pickle, glob

def bytes_to_unicode(ob):
    t = type(ob)
    if t in (list, tuple):
        l = [str(i, 'utf-8') if type(i) is bytes else i for i in ob]
        l = [bytes_to_unicode(i) if type(i) in (list, tuple, dict) else i for i in l]
        ro = tuple(l) if t is tuple else l
    elif t is dict:
        byte_keys = [i for i in ob if type(i) is bytes]
        for bk in byte_keys:
            v = ob[bk]
            del(ob[bk])
            ob[str(bk,'utf-8')] = v
        for k in ob:
            if type(ob[k]) is bytes:
                ob[k] = str(ob[k], 'utf-8')
            elif type(ob[k]) in (list, tuple, dict):
                ob[k] = bytes_to_unicode(ob[k])
        ro = ob
    else:
        ro = ob
        print("unprocessed object: {0} {1}".format(t, ob))
    return ro

for fn in glob.glob('*.pickle'):

    data = pickle.load(open(fn, "rb"), encoding='bytes')
    ndata = bytes_to_unicode(data)
    pickle.dump(ndata, open(fn + '3', "wb"))
```

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) say:

> The pickle serialization format is guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases.

I didn't find a way to `pickle.load` Python-2.7 pickled data in Python 3.3 -- not even data that contained only `int`s and `date`s.

Comment: You should open a bug (if one doesn't already exist) on the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the implementation.

You can subclass the `Unpickler` and overwrite the byte deserialization to produce strings.